# How can I get pathname in component in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I tried to get pathname in `CustomNavbar` component using `usePathname` but it returned `null` value. However, when I call `usePathname` in `/pages/index.tsx`, it worked correctly.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

### Environment

- "next": "13.4.19"
- "react": "18.2.0"
- "react-dom": "18.2.0"

### Directories

- components

  - CustomNavbar.tsx
- pages

  - _app.tsx
  - document.tsx
  - index.tsx

    .

    .

    .

### Code

```js
// CustomNavbar.tsx
"use client";

import React from "react";
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  NavbarContent,
  NavbarItem,
  Link,
  Button,
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export const CustomNavbar = () => {
  const pages = {
    home: "/",
    subscriptions: "/subscriptions",
    playlists: "/playlists",
  };
  const pathname = usePathname();
  console.log(pathname); // null
   .
   .
   .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use features from the [app router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) while using the pages directory. Specifically the `usePathname` hook is not available inside the pages directory. Here is an example how to achieve what you are looking for:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const MyPathname = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <span>
      Current pathname: <pre>{router.pathname}</pre>
    </span>
  );
};
```

Keep in mind that the "use client" directive is also not required inside the pages directory since it does not support react server components.

Comment: Thank you so much! I successfully solve the problem. 
I got an error after using `useRouter` hook but that's because I put `CustomNavbar` component in `_document.tsx` file. It works perfectly if I put it in `_app.tsx` file. I should have browsed the docs carefully. 
Anyway, thanks for your advice!